# Why NSShadow's and CALayer's shadowOffset expressed via CGSize type and not CGPoint type

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit, shadow

I wonder if there is historical reasoning *(or any reasoning at all)* behind making `shadowOffset` of `NSShadow` and `CALayer` expressed via `CGSize` type and NOT `CGPoint` type?

I believe that by its meaning, the "shadow offset" is a vector, pointing to an origin of shadow in relation to `layer.frame.origin` (or `layer.bounds.origin`). So it seems more convenient for it to be `CGPoint` instead of `CGSize`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize) of `CGSize` slightly mentions this. Note the word "_distance_ vector". I assume it would be more appropriate to use something that has actual _length_, like width and height, to represent distances, rather than points that have no length.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for the reference. But it only leads to further question - "Why did Apple choose to use CGSize to represent vectors (including negative values)?"

Comment: You didn't seem to get my point. The keyword is "distance". `shadowOffset` is a distance vector. Sizes have widths and heights, which are more like distances than the x and y of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point is a location in a coordinate space. A size describes distances in the x&y dimensions.

If you used a CGPoint for shadowOffset, it would need to be a point relative to some other point. What point? The center of the shadow path? The origin? In  terms of the bounds, or the frame?

An offset is an amount in 2 dimensions. A point is a location. It makes perfect sense to me to use a `CGSize` for `shadowOffset`, and it would **not** make sense to use a point.

Comment: Got that. Thanks!